# ¿Cómo pasar consulta de conteo mysql a eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

¿Cómo puedo hacer que esta consulta me funcione en un controlador en laravel?

```sql
select distinct a.descripcion as Evento,
       count(b.id) as Participantes
  from eventos a, users b, asistencia c
 where c.evento_id = a.id
   and c.usuario_id = b.id
```

Comment: ¿Puedes describir realmente cual es el resultado que espera y un poco la descripción de la relación entre tablas?

Comment: espero el nombre del id=nombre del evento y que se vayan contando las asistencias, sin repetir los datos, la tabla no tiene relaciones

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con este ejemplo, por lo menos para que te vayas guiando, aquí empleo lo que **Sakrow** te indicaba, el uso de los Query Builders:

```
$result = \DB::table('eventos')
            ->selectRaw('
            distinct eventos.descripcion as Evento, count(users.id) as Participantes')
            ->join('asistencia','asistencia.id','=','evento_id')
            ->join('users','users.id', '=', 'usuario_id')
            ->get();
```

Comment: muchas gracias  Daniel tu consulta me ayudo muchisimo tuve los resultados esperados.

Comment: me alegra saberlo. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Para este tipo de cosas deberías de usar el [`query builder`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions). Esto te va a permitir crear una `query` como tú quieras.

En cualquiera de los casos, lo mejor seria crear una estructura de clases que te permitiera realizar esas consultas sin tener que estar generado tú las `querys`, para eso son los `ORM` y `Laravel` tiene `Eloquent`.

Intenta hacerlo con lo que te he dejado y si tienes dudas nos comentas.